# Extracting lines from a file based on prefix

Tags: grep, awk

I need to extract all lines from file2 that begin with an id # prefix contained in file1.

File 1 is single column like:

```
324
399
408
135236
321590
```

File 2 is multi-column like:

```
1 [tab] 108 [tab] Anarchist [tab] 103985
...
324 [tab] 309 [tab] Melodies [tab] 230498
```

What's the quickest easiest way to extract just these lines from File2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ while read p; do awk '$1 == "'$p'"' file2; done < file1
```

or:

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'FNR==NR { a[$0]; next } $1 in a' file1 file2
```

- `FNR`: the number of records read from the current file being
  processed
- `NR`: total number of input records
- `FNR==NR`: is only true when `awk` is reading the `file1`
- `a[$0]`: create an array element indexed by `$0` (from `file1`)
- `$1 in a`: check whether each line being read from `file2` exists as
  an index in the array `a`

Comment: I tried this first, but received this error: awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
 FILENAME="file2" FNR=10788 NR=10790

Comment: How many columns in `file2`?

Comment: file2 is a 28G file, 11 columns

Comment: missing the FS declaration: `awk -F '\t' '...' file1 file2

Comment: @Poe, with that much data, you should be using a real database.

Comment: @jackman, thanks for the fix and yes I'm extracting only the lines I need for the database table.  I don't want the entire 28G in the database.

Answer (score 1):

bash code to do this:

```
for i in $(cat file1); do egrep "^$i\s" file2; done
```

Comment: i'm more familiar with grep, so this worked i just went with grep -m 1 -P '$i\t'

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the fastest:

```
grep -f <( sed 's/.*/^&\t/' file1) file2
```

The answers using `for` and `while` loops are going to be very slow.

The `awk` answer by quanta should work. I don't know why it wouldn't unless your line endings are non-Unix or file1 is very big.

Comment: the other method is definitely slow, but the file is very big.

Answer (score 0):

1) We can use some OR-logic of grep. For example

```
$> grep -P "^(324|399|408|135236|321590).*" file2
324 [tab] 309 [tab] Melodies [tab] 230498
```

So question is - how we can get this variable to grep?

2) We can echo file1 in single line and substitute delimiters with `|`, than add brackets.

```
$> echo `cat file1` | sed -r -e 's/([0-9])\ ([0-9])/\1,\2/g'
324,399,408,135236,321590
```

So, finally we have a variant without a for-while loops.

```
grep -P "^($( echo `cat file1` | sed -r -e 's/([0-9])\ ([0-9])/\1|\2/g'  )).*" file2
```

Comment: `echo ``cat file1`` | sed ...` -- really? How about `sed -r -e '...' file1`

Comment: @glennjackman: "echo file1 in single line"

Answer (score 0):

The `join` command GNU coreutils server just this purpose, but it is picky about its input.

```
$ sort file1 > sorted1
$ sort file2 > sorted2
$ join -t"      " sorted1 sorted2 | sort -n
```

The `join` command requires its input files to be sorted lexicographically, not numerically.  Thus, all that sorting of the inputs and the output.

To specify that the output from `join` should be tab delimited, use `-t"`*tab character*`"`, which you would type as `Ctrl-V` `Tab` at the Bash prompt.